# What word describes the painful emotion/physical sensations felt when experiencing something SO beautiful?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have looked for a single word to describe this feeling of what seems to be contradictory states of being.

I know a (very) little German, and searched there as it seems that language has more words to express complex emotions and feelings. No luck.
This to me might help to explain it.

I recently watched a clip of a little boy that started really crying  after seeing and holding a kitten. His mother asked him,

> Why are you crying?

He could barely get it out...and said,

> It’s just so beautiful!

Comment: Relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482859/is-there-an-idiom-or-expression-for-that-squeezing-sensation-you-feel-in-your-c

Comment: The single-word-request requires a sample sentence demonstrating how the single word is to be used.